# VHDL "can't match slice type array type"

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm new to VHDL and I'm trying to use code off a teacher's slide that doesn't seem to work as is, and I can't tell what's wrong:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Add4 is port (
  Data1, Data2 : in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
  Cin : in std_logic;
  Cout : out std_logic;
  Sum : out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) );
end entity Add4; 

architecture RTL of Add4 is
  signal Out5bit : unsigned(4 downto 0);
begin
  Out5bit <= ('0' & Data1) + ('0' & Data2) + Cin;
  Sum <= Out5bit(3 downto 0);
  Cout <= Out5bit(4);
end architecture RTL;
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
add4.vhd:15:28: no function declarations for operator "+"
add4.vhd:16:17: can't match slice with type array type "std_logic_vector"
```

The first error goes away if I comment out the assignment of `Out5bit` and the second goes away if I comment out the assignment of `Sum`. What am I doing wrong? Would this code have worked without being modified on some older version of VHDL or did my instructor just give me bogus code?

Comment: The example  doesn't provide valid VHDL semantics. ghdl is correct here and defaults to revision -1993 with relaxed rules for semantics corrected in -2002. A teacher who provides an invalid example should be willing to field questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ports are of "`std_logic_vector`" type but the internal signal `Out5bit` is `unsigned`.

`Numeric_std` doesn't provide an "`+`" operator that adds the first type and returns the other, so no matching "`+`" operator is visible.

Three approaches to fix this:
1) Type conversions from `std_logic_vector` to `unsigned` and back again. Ugly, but clearly describes what you are doing - interpreting a `std_logic_vector` (essentially a bag of bits) as an unsigned number.

2) "`use`" certain non-standard libraries that provide such operators. Can cause ambiguities especially if you also have `signed` data...

3) Declare the ports `unsigned`. In addition to just working, it clarifies the design intent - this unit operates on `unsigned` data (not signed, or arrays of boolean flags, or character data etc)

You also have to coerce "`Cin`" to an unsigned number as Elliot points out...

`Cin` is a std_logic

`(0 => cin)` is a 1-bit array of std_logic (which should be compatible with `unsigned`). Note the syntax uses "named association" ... the "positional association" version of a 1 bit vector would be `(Cin)` which the compiler cannot detect as a vector unlike the 3 bit vector `(Cin,Cin,Cin)`

`unsigned'(0 => cin)` is explicitly unsigned.

Comment: Thanks, if I change Data1, Data2, Cin and Sum to unsigned it works. But just for learning I decided to also try the type conversion way but I can't seem to make the compiler happy. `unsigned(Cin)` gives the error `conversion allowed only between closely related types` when Cin is std_logic. `unsigned(std_logic_vector(Cin))` doesn't work either. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks again the conversion works now too. I'm sorry to keep asking stuff but I'm at the stage where it's unclear what the terms to Google even are -- I can't find documentation for a `=>` operator, only `<=`. Is it library defined? Also why is the apostrophe necessary?

Comment: => isn't an operator, it's the "named association" token. Used in array aggregates (here) but also record aggregates, port maps, and it can be used to make argument lists in procedure calls crystal clear...

Comment: Providing a composite value for `cin` can be through concatenation to a null string whose type is determined by context. [Shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVqo6.jpg) with a -2008 (--std=08) solution, note the declaration of `Out5bit` as std_logic_vector as well as creating the composite value with `cin` through concatenation).

Comment: `Out5bit <= ('0' & Data1) + ('0' & Data2) + (0 => Cin);` works where the aggregate associating element 0 (the default letfmost element) of a composite element takes it's type from context (the entire statement, here the type of the target `Out5bit`). No qualified expression is necessary here (--std=08 using package numeric_std_unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

VHDL is a strongly typed language and you are mixing the datatypes. In line 15 you are adding `std_logic` to `std_logic_vector`. In line 16 you are trying to take a slice of an `unsigned` and assign it to a `std_logic_vector`. I'm not sure, but I suspect this is where your problems are coming from.